# Getting Android emulator (HAXM) to work on Kaby lake

Tags: windows, android-emulator, haxm

Using Windows 10, and just moved PC to a new Kaby Lake processer/motherboard.

On my old PC, the Android emulator worked in HAXM - virt-mode - but no longer on this pc. Same cloned disk copy...so software setup is the same.

I read that maybe Windows 10 is turning HYPER-V on at boot time and interferes with the emulator virt-mode. I created a new boot entry - turning it off...still no go.

Any help/suggestions?

New motherboard bios has VT-D enabled...same Windows software - only thing different is the motherboard and the cpu (gen 5-> gen 7)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

I uninstalled the Intel HAXM driver/module from Android SDK manager.

Then went to Intel site and download the HAXM program - worked fine.

Before that, made sure VT was enabled in bios, HYPER-V was disabled (Windows 10 home should be disabled) and feature supported by Kaby Lake CPUs.

Comment: To enable VT in bios, please check this video   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvpVoMXxp8Y